# symfony can not update datetime field

Tags: symfony

When symfony updates the Datetime field, the first one cannot be updated successfully, but the second one can. Who knows?

```
$plan->setPlanAt($plan->getPlanAt()->modify('+7 day')); //fail
$plan->setPlanAt(new \Datetime($plan->getPlanAt()->modify('+7 day')->format('Y-m-d')));  //success
```

Comment: The modify() method will not update the entity since Doctrine tracks DateTime objects by reference. You need to clone your existing DateTime object, giving it a new reference. Modify the new one and then set is as a new timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

the issue might come from the differences of date time formats on your web server time and database server.